# How to achieve smooth movement on an object locked on the Y-axis following mouse position?

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, game-physics

I am making an Android game in LibGDX, where the player object will move accordingly to the touch Y-position with a smooth movement, making it look like it is following the touch movement. This is my code so far, it does as supposed to, but it isn't smooth enough and sometimes it "wiggles" upon reaching the touch position (it isn't reaching distance zero, but bypasses it.):

```
if ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY) < (world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f))) { //if player is below touch
            if (Math.abs((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f))) > 20) { // if distance is more than 20
                player.getVelocity().y = Math.min(
                    Math.abs(
                        ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f)))/2f), 
                    Player.SPEED); // set velocity
            } else { // if distance is less than 20
                if (player.getVelocity().y != 0)
                    player.getVelocity().y *= 0.3f+delta; // slow down velocity
                else
                    player.getVelocity().y = Math.min(
                        Math.abs(
                            ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f)))/2f), 
                        Player.SPEED); // just so it follows even when the touch moves slightly
            }
        }

if ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY) > (world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f))) {
            if (Math.abs((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f))) > 20) {
                player.getVelocity().y = -Math.min(
                    Math.abs(
                        ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f)))/2f),
                    Player.SPEED);
            } else {
                if (player.getVelocity().y > 1) {
                    player.getVelocity().y *= 0.3f+delta;
                } else {
                        player.getVelocity().y = -Math.min(
                        Math.abs(
                            ((player.getPosition().y * world.ppuY)-(world.height-touch.y-(world.ppuY/2f)))/2f), 
                        Player.SPEED);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a better method than this that firstly makes the code shorter and secondly makes the smooth movement even better and more stable?

Comment: Not sure about your code but if you interpolate the position of the object to the position it should go to it will be way more smoth. Use this for it: `newyvalue = Interpolation.linear.apply(newyvalue , gotopos, value[0,1])`. test different values for a good look.

Comment: Thank you. Surely, made my code shorter. Make it an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to create smoth movement is to interpolate the old position to the new position with a spec value. Depending on the Value the camera or the Figure moves more smoth or less smoth. To archiev this you need to change the `setY()` to something like this:

```
currentpos.y = Interpolation.linear.apply(currentpos.y, gotopos.y, value[0,1]);
currentpos.x = Interpolation.linear.apply(currentpos.x, gotopos.x, value[0,1]);
```

Depending on the value it does interpolate the current position to the goto position. It's also useful for loadingbars or lifebars and so on that they dont "jump" to the new value.

Play around with the `value[0,1]` to find the right for your movementspeed.